# Factor variable on x-axis for double y-axis

Tags: r, plot

Right now on the x-axis it plots numerical variable "1,2,3,4" etc. when instead I want it to graph the game. As you can see in line 85, axis(1,Champ$game) I want the game name on the x-axis, but instead it just numbers the game rather than putting the game name. How do I fix this?
[image]

[image: Here is the table I am pulling from, games and names are changed for privacy purposes]

```
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 6) + 0.1)
plot(Champ$daily_max_vel, pch = 16, axes = FALSE, ylim = 
c(3.0,3.9),type = "b", col = "black", ylab = "", xlab = "",
                                main = "Athlete")
##Creates y-axis for graph 1
axis(2, ylim = c(0,1), col = "black", las = 1)
mtext("Velocity (m/s)", side = 2, line = 2.5)
box()

## Allows for second plot on same graph
par(new = TRUE)

#Plotting second graph
plot(Champ$daily_peak_power, pch = 1, xlab = "", ylab = "", 
ylim = c(1000,1600), axes = FALSE, type = "b", 
                                  col = "orange")
 #Creating Second Axis
 mtext("Power (W)", side = 4, col = "orange", line = 4)
 axis(4,ylim = c(1200,1600), col = "orange", col.axis = 
 "orange", las = 1)
 axis(1,Champ$game)
```

Comment: Could you try to give us a sample of your data, such as with `dput()` or some other method? And please use the actual code, not a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Using the `labels` function should do what you are looking for - here is an example of what I think your issue is. If this doesn't work, edit your post to provide your data structure.

```
# create sample data 
df <-  data.frame(game = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 150, replace = TRUE),val = rgamma(150, 50))
plot(df)

# label factors
df$game <-  factor(df$game, levels = 1:3, labels = c("Game A", "Game B", "Game C"))

# plot
plot(df, axes = F, type = "b")
axis(1, df$game, labels = df$game) # shows game A, game b, game c instead of 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Hi @jpsmith, I updated the question so you can see what I am working with. I don't think I would need the labels function because the game names are already in the table as a factor. Is that correct or am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Hi Ben - Factors in R are stored as integer values (behind the scenes) with a corresponding set of character values typically used when the factor is displayed (I.e., when print(df)). That’s why you are getting integers on the x-axis. By using the labels function, you are telling it to use the corresponding character value.